# Angular - scope variable doesn't properly update

Tags: angularjs

Controller:

```
function ProductListCtrl($scope, Product) {
    $scope.page = 1;

    $scope.setPage = function(page) {
        $scope.page = page;
    }

    Product.query({page:$scope.page}, function(response) {
        $scope.products = response.records;
        $scope.product_count = response.metadata.count;
        $scope.page_count = response.metadata.page_count;
    });
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->

        Search: <input ng-model="query">

        </div>
        <div class="span10">
        <!--Body content-->
            Number of products: {{product_count}}.<br>
            Page {{page}} of {{page_count}}.

            <ul class="products">
                <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp" class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="#/products/{{product.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{product.imageUrl}}"></a>
                    <a href="#/products/{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</a>
                    <span ng-repeat="category in product.categories">{{category.name}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <a href="#" ng-class="{disabled: page < 2}" ng-click="setPage(page-1)">Previous page</a>
            <a href="#" ng-class="{disabled: page == page_count}" ng-click="setPage(page+1)">Next page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I click the "Next page" link, the `setPage` function is called with the correct page number (i.e. the next page), but the page variable is not updated in the view. The list is reloaded from the backend, but with the original page number.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to re-`query()` when changing page, don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like `<div ng-controller="ProductListCtrl">` around your view?

Also, `Product.query` will be called only once, so if you need to query the server again, you can wrap this into a function and call it in your `setPage` when the user clicks, i.e.:

```
var updateProducts = function() {
    Product.query({page:$scope.page}, function(response) {
        $scope.products = response.records;
        $scope.product_count = response.metadata.count;
        $scope.page_count = response.metadata.page_count;
    });
}

updateProducts(); // call it once when the controller is initialised

$scope.setPage = function(page) {
    $scope.page = page;
    updateProducts(); // call it again after the user clicks
}
```

Just setting `$scope.page` is not going to trigger `Product.query` itself, so you have to call it yourself.